# Push notification services vs Periodic server-polling for web application?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, polling

We're currently building a platform which offers both a website and a mobile app (both for iOS and Android). The website is basically ready, the mobile app being built now.

The customer desired that push notifications absolutely **MUST** be implemented for the mobile app, mainly because the web / mobile app ships a chat in it. Haven't done this before; the basics I could get is that you have to use some external push notification service, like firebase cloud messaging. Then, e.g. for your app, when user **A** sends a message to user **B**, you would send a request from your backend to your push notification service, to dispatch an according push notification to the device of user **B**.

After reading through the basics of this principle, I've checked on how the chat is currently implemented for the web frontend (Js). And it simply periodically polls the server for new messages, from clients who are logged in. Gradually extending the interval for the next poll in case of multiple subsequent "No new messages to poll" requests.

Given that we will need to implement the combination of the current backend with a push notification service for the mobile app anyway; I'm thinking that it would be better to also couple the web clients in Js with that service, instead of keeping on with the current periodic server-polling. Just sounds resource-friendlier to me. But I am unaware about the compatibility of push notification services with Js and the major browsers (Chrome, Mozilla, Safari) ? In our modern days, is an implementation of push notification services together with web applications well supported ?

Comment: "compatibility of push notification services with Js and the major browsers (Chrome, Mozilla, Safari) " https://caniuse.com/push-api has the latest on that.

Comment: Ok thx. As far as I understood, this Js API relies on service workers, and these need user permission to receive notifications, correct? Feels odd to me if I would need to prompt customers to consent to being notified about new messages, every time they login on a new device / their cookies / local storage is deleted. Opposed to the fact that you could simply start polling whenever a customer logs in with the polling approach. Or am I wrong with this thought?

Comment: On mobile, you can only reliably poll for updates from an app that is actively being used. When the app is not actively being used, the ability to perform such polling either disappears completely or becomes unreliable at best.

Comment: In other words you‘re saying stick to polling for web and rely on push notifications for the app?